# Trouble with a simple inner join for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

**EDIT:** Made a little change. Added table `db_supplier (Supplier_ID, Supply_Speed_ID)` and changed `lookup_supply_speed (Supplier_ID, Supplier_Speed)` to `lookup_supply_speed (Supplier_Speed_ID, Supplier_Speed)`

My tables:

```
db_supply
 -----------------------------------------------
| Supplier_ID | Supply_Type_ID | Itm_ID | Stock |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| 1           | 1              | 33     | 3     |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| 2           | 2              | 28     | 1     |
 -----------------------------------------------

db_supplier
 ----------------------------------------
| Supplier_ID | Supply_Speed_ID | Etc... |
|----------------------------------------|
| 1           | 1               |        |
|----------------------------------------|
| 2           | 2               |        |
 ----------------------------------------

lookup_supplier_name
 -----------------------------
| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name |
|-----------------------------|
| 1           | Walter        |
|-----------------------------|
| 2           | Jesse         |
 -----------------------------

lookup_supply_type
 -----------------------------------
| Supply_Type_ID | Supply_Type_Name |
|-----------------------------------|
| 1              | Import           |
|-----------------------------------|
| 2              | Delivery         |
 -----------------------------------

lookup_itm
 ------------------------
| Itm_ID | Itm_Name      |
|------------------------|
| 33     | Pickles       |
|------------------------|
| 28     | Burger        |
 ------------------------

lookup_supply_speed
 ------------------------------------
| Supplier_Speed_ID | Supplier_Speed |
|------------------------------------|
| 1                 | Fast           |
|------------------------------------|
| 2                 | Slow           |
 ------------------------------------

A query for 'Burger' will output this table:
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Supplier_Name | Supply_Type_Name | Itm_Name | Stock | Supplier_Speed |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Jesse         | Delivery         | Burger   | 1     | Slow           |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Problem:** I can't produce an SQL statement that would get me the `Supplier_Speed` column since the `lookup_supply_speed` does not have any FK association to `db_supply` (all the other tables do).

SQL below will give me this: (WE QUERY FOR `Itm_Name` e.g. `Burger`)

```
 -----------------------------------------------------
| Supplier_Name | Supply_Type_Name | Itm_Name | Stock |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
| Jesse         | Delivery         | Burger   | 1     |
 -----------------------------------------------------
SELECT  b.Supplier_Name,
        c.Supply_Type_Name,
        d.Itm_Name,
        a.Stock
FROM    db_supply a
        INNER JOIN lookup_supplier_name b
            ON a.Supplier_ID = b.Supplier_ID
        INNER JOIN lookup_supply_type c
            ON a.Supply_Type_ID = c.Supply_Type_ID
        INNER JOIN lookup_itm d
            ON a.Itm_ID = d.Itm_ID
WHERE   d.Itm_Name = 'Burger'
```

How can I modify this so that I can join `lookup_supplier` with `lookup_supply_speed` **via `db_supplier`** and then join it to the rest?

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9635d/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
SELECT  f.Supplier_Name,
        b.Supplier_ID,
        c.Supply_Type_Name,
        d.Itm_Name,
        a.Stock,
        e.Supplier_Speed
FROM    db_supply a
        INNER JOIN db_supplier b
            ON a.Supplier_ID = b.Supplier_ID
        INNER JOIN lookup_supplier_name f
            ON f.supplier_ID = b.supplier_ID
        INNER JOIN lookup_supply_type c
            ON a.Supply_Type_ID = c.Supply_Type_ID
        INNER JOIN lookup_itm d
            ON a.Itm_ID = d.Itm_ID
        INNER JOIN lookup_supply_speed e
            ON e.Supplier_Speed_ID = b.Supply_Speed_ID
WHERE   d.Itm_Name = 'Burger'
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be1a2/3

Comment: Thanks, can you adapt this to my question edit? I felt that the lookup table for speed wasn't really a lookup table if it contains Supplier_ID instead of it's own definition IDs.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me :)

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to refer to other tables than the `from` table in the `on` clause:

```
INNER JOIN lookup_supply_speed ss
    ON ss.Supplier_ID = b.Supplier_ID
```

(You aliases `b` to lookup_supplier.)

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. I've made a little change to my question: `lookup_supply_speed (Supplier_ID, Supplier_Speed)` to `lookup_supply_speed (Supplier_Speed_ID, Supplier_Speed)`.  Added `db_supplier` which bridges the relationship between `supplier_id` and `supplier_speed_id`.

Comment: Sorry for the random edit, I felt that the lookup table for speed wasn't really a lookup table if it contains `Supplier_ID` instead of it's own definition IDs.